# Is there any formula to show me what was my age in specific year in excel?

Tags: excel

So i want to know how old someone was in some specific year for example if someone's date of birth is `5/3/1987` and now his age is `33` so i want to find out how old he was in lets say `2003` using some sort of formula in excel.. i tried different `function` to try to acheive it but no success .

Comment: In 2003 before 5/3 or after 5/3?

Comment: I just need to roughly see the year only not date or day part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(A2,B2,"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF(A2,B2,"MD") & " Days"
```

[image]

Comment: If you want only year difference then use [YEARFRAC()](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-age-from-birthday) formula.